# Prevent Leaflet.markercluster unspiderfy on clicking child CircleMarker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to cluster [CircleMarker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circlemarker) markers. When clicking on a CircleMarker from a cluster than has been spiderfied (i.e. expanded), the cluster unspiderfies (i.e. contracts), but I would like it to remain spiderfied (open).

This is not the case with [this demo](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html), although this uses Markers rather than CircleMarkers.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the CircleMarkers, use the option [`bubblingMouseEvents: false`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circlemarker-bubblingmouseevents), which prevents the click events propagating to the map below and triggering the unspiderfy.